# Custom Powershell Cmdlet - Create hidden accessible variable

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm working on a custom Powershell Cmdlet for accessing a REST webservice.
The webservice requires me to authenticate, and when i do it returns a authenticaton-token that i have to include in every request after that.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to store the token in a desired manner so i can use it with ease in commands after the authentication.

I would like if it could work in the same way as **Connect-MSOLService** work.
For those unfamiliar with the Office 365 cmdlets i will give some examples.

**Office 365 Cmdlets**

> $Credentials = Get-Credential
>   Connect-MSOLService -Credential $Credentials
>   Get-MSOLUser

In this example the Get-MSOLUser will return every Office 365 user, because the Connect-MSOLService have been called before hand.

**My Cmdlet**

> $Credentials = Get-Credential
>   $token = Connect-WebService -Credential $Credentials
>   Get-Server -token $token
>   Get-Client -token $token

As you can see, I have to return the token and store it in a variable and use it in every call i do after the authentication.
So that leads me to my question, how can i "inject" the token into the Powershell session and use it "under-the-hood" on every command in my cmdlet/module after that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about storing the token in a process wide  variable as it is possible to have multiple PowerShell runspaces running in the same process.  However, what you could do is create a static reference to a Dictionary that stashes the token for the runspace in which the cmdlet is running.  You can get the runspace ID like so:

```
Guid runspaceId = Guid.Empty;
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace))
{
    runspaceId = ps.Runspace.InstanceId;
}
```

Then create a static class with a static readonly field like so:

```
public static class TokenUtil {
    public static readonly Dictionary<Guid,PSObject> Tokens = new Dictionary<Guid,PSObject>();
}
```

Check for existing token for this runspace like so:

```
PSObject token = null;
if (TokenUtil.Tokens.ContainsKey(runspaceId))
{
    token = TokenUtil.Tokens[runspaceId];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using the PowerShell 5.0 assembly you can inherit from `PSCmdlet` and use `SessionState` to store variables.

```
private string const variableName = "MyVar";
private Token token = new Token("your token");
SessionState.PSVariable.Set(new PSVariable(variableName, token, ScopedItemOptions.Private));
```

You then use `GetValue()` to retrieve it.

```
Token storedToken = (Token)SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue(variableName);
```

This variable is *not* available to the PowerShell session but will persist between cmdlet calls. I use it to store an API token on the first query, and to reuse it until it expires or the session is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Microsoft does it, but I think one way to do it is like this:

```
function Connect-WebService {
   param($credential)

   #Do all of the connection here


   #Set the global variable so it will be available outside of this function
   $script:token = ...
}

function Get-Server {
   param(
      $token = $script:token # By default use the globally set $token variable
  )
}
```

This way would work if you are doing everything in a PowerShell module.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention is that I'm writing the Cmdlet in C#.
I will check if it is possible to inject variables to the global variables within the C# code.

Comment: After some thoughts, even if I were able to get the token inn to the global variables I would still need to do the commands like Get-Service -token $token, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I just remembered that PowerShell also has script scoped variables that would work. I just don't know how that would work inside a C# Cmdlet as I have never written one. Is there a specific reason you are writing it in C# and not in PowerShell?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a class member variable in your Cmdlet. Your Connect-WebService sets it and your Get-Server will use it if it's not null.

Comment: I will check that out. The reason is because the webservice requires me to request data via REST then it returns it as Json which i need to serialize to classes that i can work with. It's just much cleaner and easier to do all the "dirty work" in C#

Comment: I have tried to do that but since it's a C# written Cmdlet the commands are stored in a dll, so it's not possible to have variables that all the classes can share. (In C# the commands are sepparate classes and not functions/methods within the same class)